# Synchronous form submits when posting to iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, synchronous

I have a form which POSTs data to a hidden `<iframe>` to prevent the page from changing. However I would like the Save button to perform two consecutive `submit()`s, one after the other.

```
<form name="updatedocform" id="updatedocform" method="post" action="http://foo.bar" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hiddenframe">
    ...
    <input type="submit" onclick="save(); return false;" value="Save" />
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenframe" id="hiddenframe"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function save() {
    document.updatedocform.submit();
    // change some form values here
    // alert("paused"); // if this alert is here, everything works fine
    document.updatedocform.submit();
}
```

However the second `submit()` is being called before the first one is finished loading. Is there a way to make the second submit wait for the first one to finish?

I could use a `setTimeout()` but I'd like a cleaner solution that doesn't depend on the speed of the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most basic solution (except for looping setTimeout) could be to have something like this instead of save() function

```
var firstSaving = false;
function save() {
    document.updatedocform.submit();
    firstSaving = true;
}

function secondSave() {
    if(firstSaving)
    {
        firstSaving = false;
        document.updatedocform.submit();
    }
}
```

and then on that iframe onload to have something like

```
top.secondSave();
```

Comment: I spy a semaphore! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery $.ajax()

You would have to intercept the click event of the first submit, send the form data via ajax and then you could tie into the ajax plugins complete callback function and make the second iframe submit.

```
$("submit").click(function () {
      $(this).closest("form").ajax({
          url: "test.html",
          data: $("form").serialize(),
          success: function(){
             //fire second submit event
          }
     });
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use Ajax because it doesn't directly support file upload (at least not a portable way).

Comment: In that case it might be worth checking out $.ajaxForm() plugin  http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload. This allows you to specify iframe: true as an option to do what you are trying to do.